How to scale an image in SwiftUI
How do I scale down an image in SwiftUI in a way that respects layouting?
I can do
Image("My Image")
    .scaleEffect(0.25)

Which will draw the image scaled down, but in SwiftUI layouting it will still take the same amount of space. When adding
Image("My Image")
    .resizable()
    .scaleEffect(0.25)

It will now be resizable, which is not the same thing, it may now be stretched depending on the parent view.
All answers in here:
How to resize Image with SwiftUI?
Use resizable, or scaledToFill, etc, which either make the image streched by the parent view or scale to fill space, or use .frame to set it to a specific size which I also don't want to do. I just want to take the original dimensions of the image (which I do not want to hard code), but scale them down.
Also all the answers in here: Scale down image AND frame
Rely on knowing the image size.
Apologies for the basic question but I cannot find an answer anywhere. Thanks!

You won't be able to achieve scale with frame without knowing the size of the original image. Here's a solution which takes in the name of the image and creates a UIImage to get the original size of the image.
When you scale it this way, the new frame only takes space based on the new ratio.
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    let imageName: String = "My Image"
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(self.imageName)
            .scaleImage(ratio: 0.5, imageName: self.imageName)
            .background(.red)
    }
}

extension Image {
    func scaleImage(ratio: Double, imageName: String) -> some View {
        let uiImage = UIImage(named: imageName)!
        
        var size = uiImage.size
        size = CGSize(width: size.width * ratio, height: size.height * ratio)
        
        return self
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
}


I would suggest setting a .frame of the appropriate size on the Image, then using either .scaledToFit or .scaledToFill. This way, the size of the image will be respected normally in the layout. If the frame has the same aspect ratio as the image then it doesn't really matter which of the two modifiers is used, because the resulting scaled image will be the same with both.
If you don't know the size of the image, or don't want to hard code it, the following techniques can be used to find the size when the view is shown:
1. Create the image as a UIImage
A UIImage has a size which can be read.
ZStack {
    if let image = UIImage(named: "My Image") {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: image.size.width * 0.25, height: image.size.height * 0.25)
    }
}
.border(.red)

2. Measure the size of a hidden background image
@State private var imageSize = CGSize.zero

ZStack {
    Image("My Image")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: imageSize.width * 0.25, height: imageSize.height * 0.25)
}
.border(.red)
.background {
    Image("My Image")
        .overlay {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear
                    .onAppear() {
                        imageSize = proxy.size
                    }
            }
        }
        .hidden()
}


You can use, example:
.aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 2, height: 3), contentMode: .fill) 

with resizable and other properties. It doesnt rely on image size. In this way image will not be stretched.
